# If $a$ is reducible, then is $a$ necessarily a non-unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Consider some integral domain $D$ and $a \in D$. If $a$ is reducible, then does it imply that $a$ is not a unit?

Contraposition of this statement is "if $a$ is unit, then $a$ is irreducible", which in my opinion is not true, because an irreducible element is by definition a non-unit. However, I'm struggling to find some simple counter example to this statement, i. e. find some integral domain $D$ where $a$ is reducible and unit at the same time.

Any hints on this would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Almost always, irreducibles and reducibles are nonunits *by definition*. What is your definition of "reducible" and "irreducible"?

Comment: @BillDubuque Nonzero element $a \in D$ is irreducible if $a$ is non-unit and for $b, c \in D$ if $a = bc$ then either $b$ or $c$ is a unit. I guess, reducible means "not irreducible", so contradiction of the condition for being irreducible, i. e. nonzero $a \in D$ is reducible if $a$ is unit or there exist $b, c \in D$ such that $a = bc$ and neither $b$ nor $c$ is a unit.

Comment: Your guess is wrong as explained in my first hint, i.e. irreducibles are nonunits (usually by definition). Generally we aren't interested in factorizations of units when studying divisibility problems.

Comment: @chandx Look at it this way: if $u$ is a unit and $u=bc$, then both $b$ and $c$ are units.  That would fit the definition of "irreducible" if not for the proscription that units cannot be called irreducible. To be reducible, there would have to be two things $b,c$, neither one a unit, such that $a=bc$.